# Call to pythons os.getcwd returning odd results on Lustre filesystem

Tags: filesystems, python, network-share

I don't really know if this question should be on Server Fault or Stack Oveflow, but I thought I'd try here first.

I have a python application that makes quite a lot of calls to os file system calls such as stat and getcwd. The application is being run by an SGE queue manager on a Lustre filesystem connected to the nodes by infiniband interconnect.

For the largest part the system works fine. But just occasionally a file will fail to stat, or getcwd will return my home directory rather than the directory the application had been running on. Milliseconds later it will be returning the correct result again.

I'm not the sysadmin, i'm working with the sys admin to workout what the application could be doing to cause this. I'm assured that when this happens, no error is recorded anywhere, and no record of an actual change of directory.

The problem is currently completely sporadic and we've been unable to make it reproducible.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?